# Vector binario aleatorio en C

Tags: c, random

Tengo que generar un array de números binarios aleatorios, pero de una manera un poco peculiar. Resulta que estoy simulando un medio de una determinada 'porosidad', r y 'longitud', L. El medio consiste en un array unidimensional de 0s y 1s en el que los 1s representan un sitio ocupado y los 0s representan un sitio libre. La porosidad se define como el cociente entre el número de ceros y el número de unos. El usuario introduce la longitud del medio L (suma del número de ceros y el número de unos) y la porosidad y devuelve el array. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como proceder?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder garantizar la porosidad, yo generaría una formación<sup>1</sup> con la proporción correcta de ceros y unos que posteriormente mezclaría.

Para generar la proporción correcta de ceros y unos:

```
int *formacion = malloc(sizeof(int) * longitud);

for (int i = 0; i < longitud; ++i)
    formacion[i] = (i / (float)longitud) < porosidad;
```

En C, una comparación booleana devuelve `0` o `1` como resultado, así que con una porosidad del 20% (porosidad = `0.2`) sobre una longitud de `100` debería rellenar la formación con veinte `1` y ochenta `0` (cambia la dirección de la comparación para obtener el reparto opuesto).

Lo siguiente sería mezclar la formación:

```
void mezcla(int *formacion, int longitud)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < longitud - 1; ++i) 
    {
        int posicion = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (longitud - i) + 1);
        int temporal = formacion[posicion];
        formacion[posicion] = formacion[i];
        formacion[i] = temporal;
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cUcf0PuM51gbtDas).

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, funcionó a la perfección!

Comment: @espinosa012 podrias aceptar la respuesta si sirviio?